# working out a quiz score from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one defines questions for a quiz and another table of responses to the quiz questions.

The first table has a structure as follows

```
questionID attribute value
1          title     some textQ1
1          option1   some text
1          option2   some text
1          option3   some text
1          correct   2
2          title     some textQ2
2          option1   some text
2          option2   some text
2          option3   some text
2          correct   1,2
```

The second table has responses from users

```
userID   questionID   value
user1    1            3
user2    1            2
user3    1            2
user3    2            1
user3    2            2
user2    2            3
```

I would then like to be able to get the scores for each user, for example 1 point per correct answer.

So the dataset would look like

```
user    score
user3   3
user2   1
user1   0
```

Is this possible to do in 1 query that then allows for multiple question entries and also multiple users?

Many thanks

Comment: User 3 answered the same question twice. Isn't that cheating? Or do you have to say "1 AND 2" in order to get a mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be this that you are looking for?

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/41eed/13)

```
select r.userid, 
sum(case when find_in_set(r.value, q.value) then 1
     else 0
     end) as score   
from responses r
left join questions q
on r.questionid = q.questionid
where q.attribute = 'correct'
group by r.userid
order by score desc
;

| USERID | SCORE |
------------------
|  user3 |     3 |
|  user2 |     1 |
|  user1 |     0 |
```

Comment: @Dave please take a look at this code. I have used `Find_In_Set` within the `CASE WHEN` to return a 1 whenever the user's answer is correct or in the correct pool.

Comment: That is awesome, thank you sooo much! There is so much sql I am unaware of!